# Generation logo image in email

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a problem with link generation when I try to send emails.
In my .env file :

```
WEB_LOGO="http://test.loc/build/images/logo.png"
```

In my twig.yml

```
twig:
    globals:
        web_logo: '%env(WEB_LOGO)%'
```

My email template :

```
<img align="center" alt="" src="{{ web_logo }}" height="30">
```

The problem is that when I open folder /build/images the logo image is like this :

```
http://test.loc/build/images/logo.12345.png
```

But I generate like :

```
http://test.loc/build/images/logo.png
```

I can't use the generation like `{{ absolute_url(asset('build/images/logo.png')) }}` be cause I sendind email using an external service and I'm limited. Help please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way to do it but I would use the Finder component to get the filename like that:

```
$finder = new Finder();
$directory = 'http://test.loc/build/images';
$name = 'logo';
$finder->in($directory)->name("/{$name}/")->files();
$logoFile = iterator_to_array($finder, false)[0];
$logoPath = $logoFile->getRealPath();
```

Then you can pass the $logoPath variable as argument to your twig template.

Of course there will be a problem if you have multiple logo files like 'logo.1.png' and 'logo.29.png' etc.